# Login Screen in payumoney Integration with Android app

Tags: android, payumoney

I have integrated my Android app with Payumoney payment Gateway, Our production merchantId has gone live and we are able to receive payments, but still while redirecting from my app to Payment Gateway, there is a login screen which  appeares with option to "Guest Login" or "Login with Password", actually it has Login as well as SignUP. Is there any way to bypass the login screen,Please note i am using Non-Seamless integration.

Comment: HI RKM any solutions found?? I am also facing issues. pls help. Incase if you have answer pleas post your answer

Comment: Hi Ranjith, Sure, will let u know..

Comment: contact payu support and check there sample codes also. the support will solve ur issues

Comment: i have integrated payu money but i am getting error 5014 any suggestions???

Comment: @RanjithKumar They have a new Sdk now. Follow this sample app they have given in their site https://github.com/payu-intrepos/payumoney-new-sample-app this Sdk doesn't have Login screen. But I am facing another issue, I have contacted them for the solution, will post it if everything works fine